# c++ how to store a void* in a file in binary mode

Tags: filestream, void

i have the following function that stores 2 different types of data in a `std::vector<unsigned char>` called data:

```
void vertexBufferObject::addData(void* ptrData, unsigned int uiDataSize)
{
    //data is a std::vector<unsigned char>
    data.insert(data.end(), (char*)ptrData, (char*)ptrData+uiDataSize);
    iCurrentSize += uiDataSize;
}
```

now.. once the vector is filled, i get a void* to the std::vector raw data:

```
void* vertexBufferObject::getDataPointer()
{
    return (void*)data[0];
}
```

i need to write a file with this data (getDataPointer()) in binary mode. How can i do that?:

```
//im trying this
void* result = getDataPointer();

file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&result), iCurrentSize );
```

and then.. how can i recover it safely (using read()) and store again in a `std::vector<unsigned char>`?

for Example:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> retrievePointerData;

//here im trying to get the previous saved void* in my std::vector<unsigned char>
file.fread(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&retrievePointerData), iCurrentSize );
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you mean: reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&data[0]) ?

Comment: //HERE "data" is a void* that points to (void*)data[0] (std::vector<unsigned char>)
file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&data), iCurrentSize );

Comment: Posting a compilable working demonstration would get you more interest in helping you out. Or at least not reusing the same variable names in different places with different types without explaining it.

Comment: i edited the code to clarify the situation

Comment: Your edits further confuse the situation. In your commend you said that data is void*. Now your edit suggests it is std::vector<unsigned char>. You need to make your mind up. If your current edit is accurate (which I suspect it isn't), then my first comment is closer to what you want. You can't reinterpret cast the address of a vector instance into a char*. Because its contents are stored contiguously you can possibly cast the address of the first element of the vector to a char* ptr then use it as a buffer.

Comment: thanks, but i believe that you didn't read the post again after i edited it. It's clear, i have an std::vector  unsigned char  that i filled with different data types. Then i get a void* to this vector ((void*)data[0]) and store it in a file. Finally i trying to get it back from file to std::vector unsigned char and this is my question: how can i do it safely without losing or corrupting data?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I get it now. So, I think getDataPointer() should be:

```
void* vertexBufferObject::getDataPointer()
{
    return (void*)&data[0];
}
```

i.e. return a pointer to the start of the data, not a pointer with the value of whatever the first byte of data happens to be.

Then I think your reinterpret cast should be:

```
file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(result), iCurrentSize );
```

I.e. cast the void pointer to a const char* pointer. Not the address of the void pointer - that gives you a pointer to a pointer.

As to reading it in, you need to know the size somehow before you begin - perhaps writing it first as a fixed size int to the start of the file? Anyhow, you probably just need to resize() the vector to the known size, and read in the data:

```
// We assume here that iCurrentSize is actually valid.
std::vector<unsigned char> retrievePointerData;
retrievePointerData.resize(iCurrentSize);
file.fread(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&retrievePointerData[0]), iCurrentSize );
```

I must admit, I usually use iostreams for file IO in c++, so I'm not too familar with your file.write/file.fread calls.

Also, you may want to consider not bothering with the reinterpret cast at all, and dropping the void* completely. If you just passed around unsigned char* (or better yet, typedef it to BYTE* like Win32 does) then all your types will just work with the file IO calls.